# Как удалить конкретное поле у сущности в БД Room?

Tags: android, room

У меня есть сущность и мне необходимо удалить из этой сущности данные конкретного поля, а именно необходимо удалить список - apartments. Подскажите как это сделать?

```
@Entity(tableName = "houses")
data class HouseDB(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "houseId") var houseId: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "floors") var floors: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "builderName") var builderName: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "apartments") var apartments: List<ApartmentDB> = listOf()
) {

@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Long = 0
```

}

Comment: база данных проектируется таким образом, что ее структура остается статичной, то есть в правильно спроектированной базе не требуется удаление никаких колонок в процессе работы. Если у вас возникла такая необходимость, с большой долей вероятности вы что то делаете не так и может лучше описать суть проблемы и зачем потребовалось удалять эту колонку ...

Comment: Вы хотите управлять списком зависимых сущностей один-ко-многим? возможно вам поможет https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a